# Google Cloud VM cuda not available anymore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deep-learning, google-cloud-instances, google-cloud-vm

I'm working in GoogleCloud and I have create a virtual machine with the following specs:

- Machine: a2-highgpu-1g
- CPU platfor: Intel Cascade Lake
- GPU: 1 x NVIDIA A100 40GB

I use this machine to train and test different RNN models and it was working fine till last friday ( 8th of September 2023 ) and today suddenly my models are not able to use the GPU anymore.
If i run

```html
torch.cuda.is_available()
```

the result is **false**. Someone could give me sime hints to what could be happened since the last usage since the GPU is not available anymore?
Thanks.

Edit:
I have used it since Friday but then for the weekend I kept the VM on but never used it. Maybe they restricted my account because I was occupying a machine without using it?

Edit 2:
I notice that the command: *lshw -class display* returns:

```html
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: 3D controller
       product: GA100 [A100 SXM4 40GB]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 4
       bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msix pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:200-1ff iomemory:300-2ff memory:80000000-80ffffff memory:2000000000-2fffffffff memory:3000000000-3001ffffff
```

Surfing on internet I found that "display UNCLAIMED" means that I do not have the proper driver.
Is this right? Should I upgrade manually the driver on a GCloud VM?

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can try to manually download the [CUDA toolkit](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-11.1.0-download-archive?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64) and pre-installation according to the [instruction](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/11.1.1/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html) provided. Attaching the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/install-drivers-gpu) for your reference